# how to use react-native-config to set environment variable in nx?

Tags: react-native, monorepo

I want to use react-native-config to set environment variable with nx. Is it possible to combine this two package together to achieve the goal? or just use nx environment variable setting. Any suggestion is appreciated.Thanks.

I want to use @nrwl/workspace:run-commands to run my customize script.

```
 "customCommand": {
   "executor": "nx:run-commands",
   "options": {
      "command": "react-native run-android"
   }
 }
```

when I run the command in command line.

```
npx nx run employee:make
```

It shows below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you want to run in libs or apps. I assume you try to run command in libs. Your project.json look like that:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/assets/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/assets/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}"]
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["coverage/libs/assets"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "libs/assets/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and add your command:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/assets/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "customCommand": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "command": "react-native run-android"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/assets/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}"]
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["coverage/libs/assets"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "libs/assets/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

run your command with:

```
nx run assets:customCommand
```

in case cmd not found run code below and try again:

```
nx reset
```